# Exploring IronPython using dir() doesn't always yield results

Tags: .net, ironpython

I'm playing around with IronPython and dir() does not always seem to work as I would expect.  For instance:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("IronPython")
clr.AddReference("Microsoft.Scripting")
from IronPython.Hosting import Python
py = Python.CreateEngine()
print dir(py.Operations)
```

Returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
TypeError: __dir__() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

Ideas? Or is this some sort of bug?

Comment: help(py.Operations) does something useful....but that does not answer your question :(

Comment: That looks like a bug - we manufacture a __dir__ method for certain types but I don't know why we would manufacture one for ObjectOperations.